# StackOverflowError when trying to fill join table in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many, stack-overflow

I get StackOverflowError when tyring to fill join table...see Code below.

I have two Entites:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;
    
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
      name = "user_appointment", 
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "appointment_id"))
    Set<Appointment> subscribedAppointments;
    
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Appointment {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long appointmentId;
            
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subscribedAppointments")
    Set<User> subscribers; //users who added this appointment to their calendar
}
```

When I try to fill the join table as following:

```
user.setSubscribedAppointments(appointment); //sheikh fuad
appointment.setSubscribers(user);
        
appointmentRepository.save(appointment);
userRepository.save(user);
```

I get StackoverflowError:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:102) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException.<init>(ReflectiveOperationException.java:89) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(InvocationTargetException.java:73) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor60.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at com.taqwaapps.entity.Country$HibernateProxy$pGwXHWph.hashCode(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.taqwaapps.entity.City.hashCode(City.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at com.taqwaapps.entity.City$HibernateProxy$9IT2B41W.hashCode(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.taqwaapps.entity.District.hashCode(District.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.taqwaapps.entity.Appointment.hashCode(Appointment.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$Set12.hashCode(ImmutableCollections.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at com.taqwaapps.entity.User.hashCode(User.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.taqwaapps.entity.Appointment.hashCode(Appointment.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$Set12.hashCode(ImmutableCollections.java:520) ~[na:na]
...
```

Then these three lines are repeated many many times:

```
at com.taqwaapps.entity.User.hashCode(User.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
at com.taqwaapps.entity.Appointment.hashCode(Appointment.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$Set12.hashCode(ImmutableCollections.java:520) ~[na:na]
```

Is it correct to set the appointments for the user and vice versa? Or how to fill the join table which was generated by spring?

Comment: first save user, then save appointment.

Comment: Same error occurs.

Comment: provide more code for here `user.setSubscribedAppointments(appointment); //sheikh fuad
appointment.setSubscribers(user);
        
appointmentRepository.save(appointment);
userRepository.save(user);`

Comment: Looks like you do have few more entities `com.taqwaapps.entity.District.hashCode(District.java:21)`  & `com.taqwaapps.entity.City.hashCode(City.java:25) `  which might be having some issues. can you check on these 2 entities.

Comment: The Error occurs when line user.setSubscribedAppointments(appointment);  is executed.

Comment: Kindly see my edited Question (End).

Comment: Do you implement equals and hashcode in your entities? If yes, the update your question with them.

Comment: I don´t do...should I ? I´m using Lombok which generates these for me. @pringi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you are using *Lombok*'s annotation `@EqualsAndHashCode`.

If you check the generated code, you will see that *User* is calling the `Set`of Appointments (probably backed by `HashSet`) hashcode. The same is true for *Appointment* that is calling *Set* of Users hashcode.

Lombok generates something like this:

```
  public int hashCode() {
    final int PRIME = 59;
    int result = 1;
    final Object $set = this.getSet();
    result = result * PRIME + ($set == null ? 43 : $set.hashCode());
    return result;
  }
```

If you see the JDK source code for HashSet hashcode:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = 0;
    Iterator<E> i = iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        E obj = i.next();
        if (obj != null)
            h += obj.hashCode();
    }
    return h;
}
```

The set is being iterated for calculating each member hashcode.

Since you are doing this:

```
user.setSubscribedAppointments(appointment); //sheikh fuad
appointment.setSubscribers(user);
```

A call to hashcode is triggered in both setXXX.

The stackoverflow is probably occurring in the second line, since user as appointment and appointment has the same user. When calculating the hashcode, one calls the other over and over again.

You need to break this dependency in hashcode calculation (probably the same occurs in equals method). You need to remove, or configure the @EqualsAndHashCode, so it does break at some point the calculation. If you implement hashcode by yourself, then the easier solution is to calculate using only the primary key (if the entity is persisted) for example. If the entity is not persisted, then you can use some other fields, but taking into attention the circularity that can occur in the calculation (you have to avoid/break it).

Comment: added hashcode and it worked (Y).

Answer (score 1):

Try it in this order..it might help you save the record.

```
appointment.setSubscribers(user);
appointmentRepository.save(appointment);
user.setSubscribedAppointments(appointment); //sheikh fuad
userRepository.save(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Appointment is dependent on user_id, which is null when you are going to save appointment. So first save user without setting appointment in it. Then set user for appointment and save it. Finally, set appointment for user and save it again. which means you must have the following lines:

```
userRepository.save(user);
appointment.setSubscribers(user);
appointmentRepository.save(appointment);
user.setSubscribedAppointments(appointment); 
userRepository.save(user);
```